# Игнорирование ошибок

Tags: golang

Возник вопрос касательно закрытия тела для каждого HTTP-запроса, почему в официальной документации, как и в обычных примерах из книг не выполняется проверка ошибки при закрытии тела? Из-за того, что в случае такой ошибки, нет смысла как-то её логировать или в таком случае исправить её никак нельзя?

```go
resp, err := http.Get("https://google.com")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Часто подобное игнорирование встречается и при записи данных в `ResponseWriter` для функций-обработчиков, т.е. также выполняется без какой-либо проверки со стороны программиста.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("hello"))
}
```

Поэтому возникает вопрос – как понять, в каких случаях возможно игнорировать ошибки, а в каких – нет? Ведь обработка ошибок в Go – это важная часть программы и подобное игнорирование как будто бы не следует философии языка в этом отношении.

Comment: Есть аналогичая тема в англоязычной версии сайта. Там тот же пример обсуждают
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293975/should-i-error-check-close-on-a-response-body

Comment: судя по приведённому обсуждению выше нет смысла обрабатывать ошибку для Close, так как если она и произойдёт, то не окажет какого-либо эффекта на выполнение программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше утверждение, что в примерах не обрабатывают ошибки, не верно.

Вот [пример из официальной документации](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#example-Get)

```go
func main() {
    res, err := http.Get("http://www.google.com/robots.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    body, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if res.StatusCode > 299 {
        log.Fatalf("Response failed with status code: %d and\nbody: %s\n", res.StatusCode, body)
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", body)
}
```

В случае ошибок здесь вызывают `log.Fatal`. Это почти как `panic`, только печатает дополнительные сведения. То есть в примерах просто убивают программу, если что-то пошло не так

В общем же случае ошибки нужно обрабатывать всегда и как минимум выводить их в лог. Ну и разумеется никогда не связываться с возвращаемым значением, если ошибка не nil.

Comment: В контексте вашего примера, да, всё понятно, если нет ошибки, то двигаемся по телу функции, а если есть, то прерываем её выполнение и передаём соответствующее пустое значение и ошибку, или логируем её как-либо с завершением как у вас или без. Вопрос именно в том, что даже ваш пример не смотрит на значение ошибки для строки `res.Body.Close()`, хотя для функции `Close()` интерфейса [`io.Closer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Closer) возвращается `error`, т.е. в этом примере такой сценарий не рассматривается даже как вероятный, как будто бы такого произойти никогда не может.

Comment: @eversince да, с точки зрения пуризма, нужно обработать ошибку `res.Body.Close()`. Вопрос - как обработать? После  того, как скопировали тело ответа в память, оно никак более не используется. Поэтому я согласен с авторами примера: наплевать.

Comment: в таком случае становится понятно, почему можно не тратить на обработку этой ошибки время.